# Can't get custom admin roles for each server discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a "system" where people can change the role that has access to admin commands, however it throws me an error that I don't understand how could be possible

Code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefixes.json", 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]


@bot.command(name="changeadminrole", help="Choose the role that can execute admin commands")
async def changeadmin(ctx, role: Role):
    with open("admins.json", 'r') as f:
        admins = json.load(f)

    admins[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.name

    with open("admins.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(admins, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to {role.mention}")
```

Then to check if people have the required role I just do this:

```
@bot.command(name="kick", help="Kicks a member from the server")
@commands.has_role(get_adminrole)
```

Even tho I have the role it throws me this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole: Role <function get_adminrole at 0x03977220> is required to run this command.
```

Idk why is it retrieving that (`<function get_adminrole at 0x03977220>`) instead of the role name present in the `admins.json` file:

```
{
    "506201000374435850": "Absolute Admin"
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the whole code I used to do it.

I just got the role here you can continue with the rest of the code.

```py
@bot.command()
async def changeadmin(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
    # Code here
    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to {role.mention}")
```

It is better if you save the role id insted of name so that you can skip `role = ....` and just `return admins[str(message.guild.id)]`

```py
def get_adminrole(message):
    with open("admins.json", 'r') as f:
        admins = json.load(f)
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=admins[str(message.guild.id)])
    return role.id
```

Here is a work around of how to use the kick command

```py
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx):
    admin_role_id = get_adminrole(ctx)
    if ctx.author not in ctx.guild.get_role(admin_role_id).members:
        await ctx.send("You are not an Admin")
        return

    # code here
```

Comment: I did what you told and now I hav the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` error... Its was located in the `get_adminrole` function `return role.id`

Comment: Make sure that there is a role with the given name in your guild. If you print the `role` it will show you `None`

Comment: Fixed it.. isntead of `role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=admins[str(message.guild.id)])` like you suggested I used `role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=admins[str(message.guild.id)])`